# Не получается прижать к низу элемента плитки цену и кнопку

Tags: html, css

Верстаю плитку на `html и css`. Размеры всех элементов одинаковые. Но никак не удается прижать кнопку и цену к низу карточки так, чтобы они на всех и всегда составляли одинаковый отступ от нижней границы карточки, заметила, что отображение зависит от текста над картинкой. Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста

```css
.item {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #778899;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: Snow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*transition: all 500ms linear 0ms;*/
  overflow: auto;
}

.info p {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.info p:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 4px rgba(192, 192, 192);
  z-index: 10;
}

.two {
  /*overflow: visible;*/
  /*position: relative;*/
}

.price {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  bottom: 0 auto;
}

.item .buy {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: White;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  bottom: 0 auto;
}

.item a:hover {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.iframe {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

img {
  /*margin-top: 15px;*/
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <a class="info">
    <p>Apple Iphone 8 256Gb</p>
  </a>
  <div class="iframe" width="150" height="150">
    <img src="images/213039.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <p class="price">89 900 р.</p>
    <a class="buy">Купить</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a class="info">
    <p>Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 64Gb Silver
      <p>
  </a>
  <div class="iframe" width="150" height="150">
    <img src="images/154.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <p class="price">10 100 р.</p>
    <a class="buy">Купить</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/popos/nm0pcxjo/24/)

Answer (score 1):

Тут либо статические размеры задавать, либо есть вариант для вашего случае с помощью верстки (в голову пока не пришло), но могу предложить литл-скрипт, он будет вычислять разницу по высоте у объектов, и добавлять отступ снизу картинки. Его можно доработать, и сделать более умное управление вкл/выкл, если к примеру данные у вас в автомате подгружаются. В текущем варианте при событиях resize и DOMContentLoaded, будет пересчет. В принципе можно и один раз выполнить, все зависит от задачи.

```js
  (function() {
    var cards = document.querySelector(".cards");
    function reSizes() {
      var maxHeight = 0;
      for(var j=0; j<cards.children.length; j++) {
        if(cards.children[j].getBoundingClientRect().height > maxHeight) {
          maxHeight = cards.children[j].getBoundingClientRect().height;
        }
      }
      for(var j=0; j<cards.children.length; j++) {
        if(cards.children[j].getBoundingClientRect().height < maxHeight) {
          var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(cards.children[j]);
          var num = Number(computedStyle.paddingTop.replace("px", '')) * 2;
          cards.children[j].querySelector("img").style.marginBottom = (maxHeight - cards.children[j].getBoundingClientRect().height + num) + "px";
        }
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", reSizes, false);
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", reSizes, false);
  })();
```

```css
  .cards {
    background-color: #e1ffff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .cards .card {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #79888b;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 15px;
  }
  .cards .card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 4px rgba(192, 192, 192);
  }
  .cards .card img {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto 40px auto;
  }
  .cards .card a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .cards .card .title {
     font-size: 14px;
     margin: 0px;
  }
  .cards .card .title a {
    color: black;
  }
  .cards .card .price {
    font-weight: 800;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .cards .card .pay {
    background-color: #04c9f6;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .cards .card .pay:hover {
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <h3 class="title"><a href="#">Apple Iphone 8 256Gb</a></h3>
    <img height="150" src="https://d3qvyelyymjydd.cloudfront.net/wp-content/themes/iphone7/images/iphone8/intro-phone8.png" alt="">
    <span class="price">89 900 р.</span>
    <a class="pay" href="#">Купить</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3 class="title"><a href="#">Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 64Gb Silver</a></h3>
    <img height="150" src="https://d3qvyelyymjydd.cloudfront.net/wp-content/themes/iphone7/images/iphone8/intro-phone8.png" alt="">
    <span class="price">89 900 р.</span>
    <a class="pay" href="#">Купить</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3 class="title"><a href="#">Apple Iphone 8 256Gb</a></h3>
    <img height="150" src="https://d3qvyelyymjydd.cloudfront.net/wp-content/themes/iphone7/images/iphone8/intro-phone8.png" alt="">
    <span class="price">89 900 р.</span>
    <a class="pay" href="#">Купить</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ссылка на вариант, где код срабатывает только один раз после загрузки документа(http://playcode.io/113644?tabs=console&index.html&output)

Comment: желательно чисто версткой, пробовала также решить проблему с помощью flex и overflow, но безуспешно

Comment: Все таки Flex - решает! (https://playcode.io/flex_cadrs)

Comment: только там одна проблема, теперь нужно, чтобы отступ от картинки до цены с кнопкой был одинаковый всегда, и, если картинка большая, то отображалась только ее центральная часть

Comment: К примеру можно задействовать, использование фонового изображения размещенного по центру для контейнера с фиксированной высотой, все изображения, что подходят то отображаются полностью, а все выходящие за пределы будут по краям обрезаны. Отступ там до нижнего блока и верхнего - постоянный, но выглядит это не очень красиво. (https://playcode.io/113736).
Может есть конкретный пример как это выглядит?

Answer (score 1):

Верхнему и нижнему элементу пришлось задавать статическую высоту.
Общая высота карточки осталась резиновой.

```css
.item {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 220px;
  border: 1px solid #778899;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: Snow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}

.info p {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.info p:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 4px rgba(192, 192, 192);
  z-index: 10;
}

.one,
.two {
  margin: 4px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(#eee, #ccc, #eee);
}

.price {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 6px;
  bottom: auto;
}

.item .buy {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: White;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 6px;
  bottom: auto;
}

.item a:hover {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.iframe {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

img {
  margin: 6px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="one">
    <a class="info">
      <p>Apple Iphone 8 256Gb</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="iframe" width="150" height="150">
    <img src="https://vip-service.kh.ua/sites/default/files/mobk.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <p class="price">89 900 р.</p>
    <a class="buy">Купить</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="one">
    <a class="info">
      <p>Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 64Gb Silver
        <p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="iframe" width="150" height="150">
    <img src="https://vip-service.kh.ua/sites/default/files/mobk.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <p class="price">10 100 р.</p>
    <a class="buy">Купить</a>
  </div>
</div>
```